# power series help for real this time

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm given $$f(x)= \frac{1}{x+2} $$
I know i have to make it look like:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} $$
but I have no clue how to go about that. Any suggestions? or maybe I could divide by 2 throughout?

Comment: oh thanks i didn't know about that.

Comment: No problem. Please consider going through your old questions and accepting answers.

Comment: I was just about to do that. You guys on Math.stackexchange are so freaking helpful, especially compared to stackoverflow

Comment: MathOverflow is a different kind of site. It's not that they are bad people, the site simply has a different purpose. A lot of people on MSE are on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$$\frac1{2+x}=\frac12\frac1{1+\frac x2}\;,\;\;\left|\frac x2\right|<1\iff\ldots$$

Comment: Enjoy my mental up vote as I'm capped.